# Make PHP Working in Many Ports

Tags: php, apache, tornado

Is there any possible way to make PHP run on both ports 80 and 8800? If yes please tell me instructions how to do it. I am using apache2 as my HTTP server.

EDIT: I am actually trying to make PHP work into tornado framework which runs on port 8800.

Comment: It should work on any port unless you've done something weird in your httpd.conf

Comment: It doesnt for me. I am using tornado as framework and I run it on port 8800. PHP doesnt load.

Comment: PHP is just the gateway. Apache hosts the virtual servers that listen to the ports. You need to alter your Apache config.

Comment: Also, Tornado is a Python framework right?

Comment: You need to configure apache to listen to those ports, not PHP. http://serverfault.com/questions/28041/how-do-i-make-apache-web-server-listen-on-two-different-ports

Comment: @SteveEdson Yes but I am trying to make a PHP login work at it.

Comment: Everybody please view updated question.

Comment: @geotsak I have not used tornado previously, but maybe this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447342/how-can-i-start-multiple-tornado-server-intances-in-multiple-ports

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking more about having apache run on multiple ports. If this is the case you should simply have to edit your apache config to have the following:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

You will likely need to add virtual hosts for both of these ports ie:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\WWW\test.com\public_html"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:\WWW\test.com\public_html"
</VirtualHost>
```

Once this has been done you need to restart the apache service.

Comment: Please view edited question.